# Как в EditText сделать формат ввода MM/YY?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Нужно, чтобы при вводе в EditText двух чисел(MM), после этого автоматически проставлялся символ "/" и продолжался ввод других двух чисел(YY). Например, 03/11.

Comment: гляньте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20611791/5330439)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889503/5698593

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону библиотеки  Decoro https://habrahabr.ru/company/tinkoff/blog/312968/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   private void birthdayTextChangeListener() {
    TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
        String current = "";
        String ddmmyyyy = "ДДMMГГГГ";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                String clean = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                String cleanC = current.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

                int cl = clean.length();
                int sel = cl;
                for (int i = 2; i <= cl && i < 6; i += 2) {
                    sel++;
                }
                if (clean.equals(cleanC)) sel--;

                if (clean.length() < 8) {
                    clean = clean + ddmmyyyy.substring(clean.length());
                }

                else {

                    int day = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(0, 2));
                    int mon = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(2, 4));
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(4, 8));

                    if (mon > 12) mon = 12;
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon - 1);
                    year = (year < 1900) ? 1900 : (year > 2100) ? 2100 : year;
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

                    day = (day > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)) ? cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE) : day;
                    clean = String.format("%02d%02d%02d", day, mon, year);
                }

                clean = String.format("%s/%s/%s", clean.substring(0, 2),
                        clean.substring(2, 4),
                        clean.substring(4, 8));

                sel = sel < 0 ? 0 : sel;
                current = clean;
                editText.setText(current);
                editText.setSelection(sel < current.length() ? sel : current.length());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    editText.addTextChangedListener(tw);


}}
```